# pygame mouse event not registered properly

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code, very simple:

```
import pygame

def run_game():

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))

    while True:

        screen.fill((55,55,55))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())


        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

When I click on one position, it shows the (x,y) coordinate. When I click on position one, it shows (x1,y1), then SOMETIMES after I change my mouse to position 2, and click on it, it still shows (x1,y1) instead of the correct coordinate. When this happens, if I don't move my mouse and keep click on position 2, it will keep showing (x1,y1) until I change mouse to somewhere else. Can someone explains to me why is that happened? Thanks.

Comment: btw I'm using mouse touchpad on macbook, if that matters.

Comment: even if I comment out the whole MOUSEMOTION elif statement it still not working. so it has nothing to do with the MOUSEMOTION statement.

Comment: BTW: for different events you have different values in `event` - for `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `MOUSEMOTION` you have position in `event.pos` - see more in yellow table on http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html

Comment: After trying both on my pc and mac, the problem is Macbook itself not handling mouse event detection well. The same program works perfectly on pc with a mouse. But even when I connect my mouse to Mac it still not working properly, so that problem is not the touchpad but some settings on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a print statement before mouse motion and mouse down so that you can easily differentiate between both.

Comment: even if I comment out the whole MOUSEMOTION elif statement it still not working.

Comment: No the mouse motion catches the motion of mouse and the pygame.mouse.get.pos() returns the position of mouse

Comment: and the mousebuttondown also using the pygame.mouse.get.pos() so they are returning same values thats why i told you so that you can see when which event is happning

Comment: I have commented out MOUSEMOTION event statement all together, so now it only detect MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event, so when I click mouse it print the position. My problem is there is a delay on that print statement, namely when I click on position 2, it still print out position 1's coordinate.

Comment: I tried that when i click on position one it print position one and then i click on different position it print different position value not that which was printed on position one.

Comment: It works perfectly on Windows, I think the problem is Mac itself